# What's the default Python version in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

I am trying to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04

During update, I get an error

```
Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the ’/usr/bin/python3’ symlink.
```

I know changing the symlink to the correct version should help. But I cannot Find info as to which version of Python does Ubuntu 22.04 ship with.

If anyone can tell that will be great .

Comment: `readlink -f /usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3.10` python3.10 is default.

Comment: Same here, `python3.10`

Comment: My current version on 20.4 is Python 3.10.9, but upgrade is not going forward. What is the minor number that showing on your side ?

Comment: Does `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` help? Or did you manually change the link before?

Comment: Never, ever change the Ubuntu-provided version of Python. That causes big problems, as you have discovered to your sorrow. Use virtual environments for other releases of Python. Or use six-month releases of Ubuntu (instead of LTS) to get newer software. You must uninstall those non-Ubuntu Python 3.10 packages and restore your older version of Python for the release-upgrade to work. Or backup your data and fresh-install 22.04...or 22.10.

Comment: I had to change it because of the application that is installed. Cant really help it there.

Comment: @frewper What do you mean by `because of the application that is installed`? Did the python version automatically change during the upgrade process?

Comment: Consider reinstalling default version of python with `sudo apt install --reinstall python3`.

Comment: no I mean the application needed a higher version of Python. i.e 3.10. Hence it was upgraded on 20.04. Now Since Ubuntu needed to be upgraded to 22.04, is when i got this issue.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi If I just reinstall Python3 doesnt that just upgrade the version of Python? That may not work since I am already on a higher version than what 22.04 comes with.

Comment: "*Cant really help it there*" yes you could have: Virtual environments for different versions. Or a different release of Ubuntu that did meet the requirements. You mangled your Ubuntu system into a [Frankensystem](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) by choice.

Answer (score 5):

https://packages.ubuntu.com will readily provide current package version information for all supported releases of Ubuntu.

For example, here's a search of that website for the `python3` package in `jammy` (22.04):

- You can see that the package version is 3.10.4.

[image: https://packages.ubuntu.com screenshot]

Comment: Does it mean I need to downgrade from 3.10.9 to 3.10.4 ?

Comment: No, it means the final result will be 3.10.4. You must downgrade to a lower version (3.10.3 or lower) AND disable all non-Ubuntu sources so apt will properly upgrade you to the correct version from the correct source.